# How to show the page user is in in navigation menu bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a static website. I wanted to show the current tab user is viewing in different color(other thn the normal navigation menu tabs). How can I do this without using any server side scripting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sample code will be helpful @EnterJQ

Comment: You mention "server side scripting" but the only tags on this are for front-end languages. What have you already tried? Does your active navigation menu tab have a certain class to differentiate it from the others? What server side language are you using?

Comment: you can use javascript or jquery but if can you share your code with us its better.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I said its static website. Just few interconnected static pages to show some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you organize your logic...For example if you have Front Controller and you get the current page which should be displayed by `GET` parameter (`page`) you can:

**PHP**

```
$current = $_GET['page'];
print '<ul class="menu">';
while ($page = $pages->getNext()) {
   $label = $page->getLabel();
   if ($page->getName() === $current) {
      print '<li class="menu-item selected">' . $label . '</li>';
   } else {
      print '<li class="menu-item">' . $label . '</li>';
   }
}
print '</ul>';
```

As you see in the script we print different type of list item depending on whether this is the current page or not. If that's the current page our list item has classes `selected` and `menu-item` otherwise it's only a menu item.

If you want to do the same thing from the front-end you can use the following approach:

**JavaScript**

```
   var menuItems = {
       'info': {
           'label': 'Info',
           'id': 'info-item'
        },
       'home': {
           'label': 'Home',
           'id': 'home-item'
        }
   };
   //...
   function getCurrentPage() {
       var str = window.location.search.replace('?', ''),
           params = str.split('&');
       for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i += 1) {
           var current = params[i].split('=');
           if (current[0] === 'page') {
              return current[1];
           }
       }
       return undefined;
   }
   //...
   var page = getCurrentPage();
   clearCurrentPage();
   setCurrentPage(page);

   //...

   function setCurrentPage(page) {
      var item = pages[page];
      document.getElementById(item.id).className += ' selected';
   }

   function clearCurrentPage() {
      var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
      for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i += 1) {
          selected[i].className = selected[i].className.replace(' selected', '');
      }
   }
```

Comment: I know I can do this. But can I do it from front end only?

Comment: Yes, i'll add one more example. I didn't understand your question...

Comment: I added a sample code which will do the same thing but with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

from what you say, your website is formed of let's say 3 pages: index.html, about.html, contact.html
and your navigation which is common on all 3 pages is Home About Contact, and menu looks like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

then in index.html you should add class="active" on first link, in about.html add class="active" on the about link and so on

then in your css file define ul li a.active { background:yellow  }

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a static website. I wanted to show the current tab user is viewing in different color(other thn the normal navigation menu tabs).

Make the `li` representing that tab a member of a class (e.g. `class="tab current-page"`). Then style it differently.

> How can I do this using any server side scripting?

- Edit the HTML manually
- Generate the HTML using a preprocessor
- Do it client side with JS that compares `location.href` to the possible pages